# trying to understand function construction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand function construction so I can cut down on my repeated code. All the snippets I have see deal with returning values and was hoping someone could shed some light on why this doesn't work.

```
<div id = 'box1' style = 'background-color: green; height: 100px; width: 50px' >
</div>

var box =  $('#box1');


function pushCard(x){
    if(x.style.opacity == 0.5){
    x.style.opacity = 1;
}
else {
x.style.opacity = 0.5;
}

}

box.click(pushCard(box));
```

Comment: You are assigning the result of the `pushCard` function call to the click handler instead of the actual function. Try `box.click(pushCard.bind(null, box.get(0)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to call the function as you pass it. You can just pass the function, then when you click it will pass the event. The element is the event `target`

```js
var box = $('#box1');


function pushCard(event) {
  let x = event.target
  if (x.style.opacity == 0.5) {
    x.style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    x.style.opacity = 0.5;
  }
}

box.click(pushCard);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box1' style='background-color: green; height: 100px; width: 50px'>
</div>
```

You can also use `this` to get the clicked object:

```js
var box = $('#box1');

function pushCard() {
  if (this.style.opacity == 0.5) {
    this.style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    this.style.opacity = 0.5;
  }
}

box.click(pushCard);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='box1' style='background-color: green; height: 100px; width: 50px'>
</div>
```